# Is there is a way to asign a certain value to a set of decision variables in ILOG CPLEX?

Tags: linear-programming, opl

I am new to the community and to the software (IBM ILOG CPLEX Optimization Studio). I am solving a production problem modeled as an integer program. Each integer variable is a three-dimensional decision variable:

```
dvar int p[order][center][week] in 0..1;
```

Certain orders need to be canceled before others, e.g. the order #1 needs to be fully processed by the second week, while order #2 could potentially wait until the sixth week. How can I express that in the software? I.e. p[i=1][center][week=3...6] = 0?

Answer (score 0):

In the upper bounds OPL allows conditions and you can use the ternary operator ?:

```
range order=1..6;
range center=1..4;
range week=1..6;
dvar int p[o in order][c in center][w in week] in 0..(((o==1)&&(w in 3..6))?0:1);

maximize sum(o in order,c in center,w in week) p[o][c][w];
subject to
{
  
}
```

works fine